# MS Word Hidden Formatting Marks

Tags: ms-word

There is a problem with the formatting of certain .docx files.  I click to show the hidden formatting marks. There are degree symbols ("non-breaking spaces") in between many of the words, instead of a regular space.

To solve the problem: I copy and paste the degree symbol, and then I use the "find and replace" function to replace the degree symbols with a regular space.

How do I prevent this problem from occurring in the first place? 
Or, how can I automatically convert these symbols to a regular space.

Comment: It's not really a problem. The degree symbols are non-breaking spaces: http://www.wordbanter.com/showthread.php?t=60109

Comment: I agree with Dan. There's no internal way to "convert", other than using Find/Replace, as you've already discovered. If you're looking for a way to perform these actions more quickly, record them in a macro. You can assign the macro to a keyboard shortcut and/or a button on your QAT or Ribbon (assuming this is version 2010 or later) so that it's available whenever you need it.

Comment: @DanL: If Tony is satisfied with our explanations, you have my permission to combine my information with yours to post as the "Answer" :-)

Comment: Why are these non-breaking spacing showing up? It seems very random and only affect 50% of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Non-breaking spaces are used to keep words from breaking across lines.

As Cindy stated above, the simplest way to remove them manually is to record a macro and execute this from a Ribbon button or the Quick Access Toolbar.

According to [this link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/word-2010-is-automatically-inserting-non-breaking/2d17bf2d-38fc-43dc-a796-b7f9c5bf7f6a?db=5&auth=1) (and [this link](http://www.wordbanter.com/showthread.php?t=38564) it refers to), nonbreaking spaces are inserted automatically if your proofing language is set to French and you type certain characters. To prevent this from happening, you have to either use a different proofing language *or* disable the "Replace straight quotes with smart quotes" option. To do this, see below (and I'm quoting the previous link):

> To change the proofing language, select the text and click Language on
>   the Review tab. In addition to choosing another language, it's a good
>   idea to uncheck the option to automatically detect the language.
>
> To change the quotes replacement, click File > Options > Proofing >
>   AutoCorrect Options, choose the AutoFormat As You Type tab of the
>   dialog (not just AutoFormat), and uncheck the first option.